# Quickblox Initialize framework from token cause crash

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm trying to Initialize the quickblox android framework.
The [documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android) say `It's also possible to initialize the SDK with an existent QuickBlox token. It can be interesting in cases when you build a big system and you have a custom server side which generates QuickBlox tokens`.
This is what i want to do because, for security reason, I don't want to keep AUTH_SECRET and AUTH_KEY in my app code.
But when i do

```
BaseService.createFromExistentToken(token, expirationDate);
```

i get `java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationId is null. You must call QBSettings.getInstance().init(Context, String, String, String) before using the QuickBlox library.`
It look a bit contradictory to me.
I generated the token server-side and it is not expired
Can anyone point me to the right direction?
Is it possible to log-in user in quickblox without AUTH_SECRET and AUTH_KEY stored in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting here the solution based on QB support team's response to my ticket.

To initialize QB

```
QBSettings.getInstance().init(getContext(), APP_ID, "", "")
```

Then I can initialize SDKs using my existent token and it's expiration date:

```
BaseService tokenService = QBAuth.createFromExistentToken(TOKEN, date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on the docs, you have to initialize QuickBlox first before using it.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Initialize_framework

```
static final String APP_ID = "961";
static final String AUTH_KEY = "PBZxXW3WgGZtFZv";
static final String AUTH_SECRET = "vvHjRbVFF6mmeyJ";
static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "961";
//
QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
```

What you did there is only creating application session but not initializing the quickblox itself.